# How to center a cell frame from a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to center my frame of the cell in a list. In the picture below is how I want it to look like:
[image]

I temporarily use the width of the frame to accomplish this result, but it isn't the right way to solve this. Does somebody have a suggestion how I can center the orange frame?

This is my code:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(splitArray(), id: \.self) { nieuwsItem in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(nieuwsItem.link).font(.title)) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(nieuwsItem.title)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                            Text(nieuwsItem.description)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("textColor"))
                                .lineLimit(3)
                        }.padding(5)
                    }.cornerRadius(10)
                }
                }.frame(width: 370, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                 .background(Color(UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8745098039, green: 0.3411764706, blue: 0, alpha: 1))))
                 .cornerRadius(20)
            //.padding(.bottom, 20)

        }//.colorMultiply(Color("backgroundColor")).padding(.top)
         .navigationBarTitle(Text("Nieuws"))
    }.onAppear {
        print("NieuwsView appeared!")
        //splitArray()
    }
}
```

Here is the code without the frame centered hard coded:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(splitArray(), id: \.self) { nieuwsItem in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(nieuwsItem.link).font(.title)) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(nieuwsItem.title)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                            Text(nieuwsItem.description)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("textColor"))
                                .lineLimit(3)
                        }.padding(5)
                    }.cornerRadius(10)
                }.frame()
                }.frame(width: 300, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                 .background(Color(UIColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8745098039, green: 0.3411764706, blue: 0, alpha: 1))))
                 .cornerRadius(20)
            //.padding(.bottom, 20)

        }//.colorMultiply(Color("backgroundColor")).padding(.top)
         .navigationBarTitle(Text("Nieuws"))
    }.onAppear {
        print("NieuwsView appeared!")
        //splitArray()
    }
}
```

Comment: At my side they are centred even w/o that `.frame` modifier. Would you show "wrong" alignment screenshot with the changed code give it?

Comment: Here is my screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/WNy2jGq.png

and my changed code, I just changed the width of the frame. I don't know how to put my code into this comment, but it is added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)`

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text(nieuwsItem.link).font(.title)) {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(nieuwsItem.title)
                .font(.headline)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                    Text(nieuwsItem.description)
                       .font(.subheadline)
                       .foregroundColor(Color("textColor"))
                       .lineLimit(3)
                    }.padding(5)
          }.cornerRadius(10)
     }
     .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```